# How could I convert onnx model to tensorflow saved model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, onnx

I am trying to use tf-serving to deploy my torch model. I have exported my torch model to onnx. How could I generate the pb model for tf-serving ?

Comment: The question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182177/how-do-you-convert-a-onnx-to-tflite/58576060#58576060 also has answer to your question.

Answer (score 19):

Use the [onnx/onnx-tensorflow](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow) converter tool as a Tensorflow backend for ONNX.

1. Install onnx-tensorflow: `pip install onnx-tf`
2. Convert using the command line tool:
   `onnx-tf convert -t tf -i /path/to/input.onnx -o /path/to/output.pb`

Alternatively, you can convert through the python API.

```
import onnx

from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

onnx_model = onnx.load("input_path")  # load onnx model
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)  # prepare tf representation
tf_rep.export_graph("output_path")  # export the model
```

Comment: With the update to tensorflow 2 `onnx-tf` changed: `onnx-tf convert -i /path/to/input.onnx -o /path/to/output.pb` is now enough. You may want to install `onnx-tf` directly from the master if you run into issues

Comment: Sorry. Doing this i get this error: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long. Can you help me too?