# Pytorch: Convert 2D-CNN model to tflite

Tags: pytorch, onnx, tensorflow-lite

I'd like to convert a model (eg Mobilenet V2) from pytorch to tflite in order to run it on a mobile device.

Has anyone managed to do so?

All I found, was a method that uses ONNX to convert the model into an inbetween state. However, this seems not to work properly, as Tensorflow expects a NHWC-channel order whereas onnx and pytorch work with NCHW channel order.

There is a discussion [on github](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow/issues/310), however in my case the conversion worked without complaints until a "frozen tensorflow graph model", after trying to convert the model further to tflite, it complains about the channel order being wrong...

Here is my code so far:

```
import torch
import torch.onnx
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

# Create random input
input_data = torch.randn(1,3,224,224)

# Create network
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.6.0', 'mobilenet_v2', pretrained=True)
model.eval()

# Forward Pass
output = model(input_data)

# Export model to onnx
filename_onnx = "mobilenet_v2.onnx"
filename_tf = "mobilenet_v2.pb"

torch.onnx.export(model, input_data, filename_onnx)

# Export model to tensorflow
onnx_model = onnx.load(filename_onnx)
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_rep.export_graph(filename_tf)
```

All working without errors until here (ignoring many tf warnings). Then I look up the names of the input and output tensors using [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) ("input.1" and "473").

Finally I apply my usual tf-graph to tf-lite conversion script from bash:

```
tflite_convert \
    --output_file=mobilenet_v2.tflite \
    --graph_def_file=mobilenet_v2.pb \
    --input_arrays=input.1 \
    --output_arrays=473
```

My configuration:

```
torch                1.6.0.dev20200508 (needs pytorch-nightly to work with mobilenet V2 from torch.hub)
tensorflow-gpu       1.14.0
onnx                 1.6.0              
onnx-tf              1.5.0
```

Here is the exact error message I'm getting from `tflite`:

```
Unexpected value for attribute 'data_format'. Expected 'NHWC'
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

**UPDATE**:
Updating my configuration:

```
torch                1.6.0.dev20200508 
tensorflow-gpu       2.2.0
onnx                 1.7.0              
onnx-tf              1.5.0
```

using

```
tflite_convert \
    --output_file=mobilenet_v2.tflite \
    --graph_def_file=mobilenet_v2.pb \
    --input_arrays=input.1 \
    --output_arrays=473 \
    --enable_v1_converter  # <-- needed for conversion of frozen graphs
```

leading to another error:

```
Exception: <unknown>:0: error: loc("convolution"): 'tf.Conv2D' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
```

**Update**:
Here is an onnx model of mobilenet v2 loaded via netron:

[image: As I said I use the vanilla mobilenet v2 architecture: no changes from my side]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Zo_tOOTRFkACxEzE4Z5LcRqnj2JRwbig?usp=sharing)  is a gdrive link to my converted onnx and pb file

Comment: You may want to upgrade your version of tensorflow, 1.14 uses an older converter that doesn't support as many models as 2.2.

Comment: Upgrading to tensorflow 2.2 leads to another error, while converting to tflite: `<unknown>:0: error: loc("convolution_7012"): 'tf.Conv2D' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op`. I guess I need an exact combination of compatible versions. It's a total dependency hell ....

Comment: sorry for the frustration -- this should work but it's hard to tell without knowing whats in the pb. Can you either post a screenshot of Netron or the graphdef itself somewhere?

Comment: @daverim I added a picture of netron  and links to the models (as I said: these are "untouched" mobilenet v2 models so I guess they should work with some configuration at least

Answer (score 2):

@Ahwar posted a nice [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58576060/2191652) to this using a Google Colab notebook.

It uses

```
torch                    1.5.0+cu101    
torchsummary             1.5.1          
torchtext                0.3.1          
torchvision              0.6.0+cu101

tensorflow               1.15.2         
tensorflow-addons        0.8.3                  
tensorflow-estimator     1.15.1         

onnx                     1.7.0
onnx-tf                  1.5.0
```

The conversion is working and the model can be tested on my computer. However when pushing the model to the mobile phone it only works in CPU mode and is much slower (almost 10 fold) than a corresponding model created in tensorflow directly. GPU mode is not working on my mobile phone (in contrast to the corresponding model created in tensorflow directly)

**Update:**
Apparantly after converting the mobilenet v2 model, the tensorflow frozen graph contains many more convolution operations than the original pytorch model ( ~38 000 vs ~180 ) as discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow/issues/473).

Comment: Thanks, @mcExchange for supporting my Answer and Spreading.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/alibaba/TinyNeuralNetwork

You can try this project to convert the pytorch model to tflite. It supports all models in torchvision, and can eliminate redundant operators, basically without performance loss